# Kivy-Python with a database

Tags: python, database, kivy

I want to build an app with Kivy/Python, but I don't know how is the connection between Kivy and MySQL. Is it like with just python?
Sorry, if this question is inappropriate.

Comment: It would be more appropriate if you included what you tried, what you expect, where you think the the problem is, and your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's like regular python.

Kivy is a framework for building user interfaces. It's up to you how to interact with your database in your app. Consider using [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model, where you have a nice separation of logic. Think about using [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as your database abstraction layer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alecxe, did you get kivy working with sqlalchemy? I've been trying to find an example of someone managing it but haven't yet. thanks

Comment: @IainDuncan I personally haven't tried this mix. There are examples out there, e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/shadowmint/7004832). `sqlalchemy` is actually pluggable and framework-agnostic. Though, if you are on android, for example, you'll need to use sqlite.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, that's what I was looking for, just proof that I could use Kivy+SQAlchemy+sqlite. Exciting! SQLAlchemy is amazing so I was hoping I could use it for a mobile app's persistence layer. :)

Comment: peewee is another good option. Its a sort of lightweight version of djangos orm , although it shares no codebase with the django orm. its rather small, so should work well with a mobile client, as you can just link against sqlite3 and it ought work.